# JasperReports customize series labels based on a value other than the Category value

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have a JasperReport with a line chart that I need to display labels on, but I want them to display conditionally for each data point.  I've created the customizer class to actually display the value, but I want to use a different field than the value field to decide if it should display or not.

Basically in my DataSet I have 3 fields:

```
Date: (Category Axis)
Value: (Value Axis)
PrintValue: Boolean field
```

I want to print the Value in the label only when PrintValue=true

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to override one of the methods implemented by JRDefaultScriptlet in a scriptlet class, then set the value of "PrintValue" in any manner you desire.  Then in your chart dataset you should be able to reference `$V{PRINTVALUE}` as an operand.

I'm going to assume your using iReport for your report design.

1. Open your report in iReport and click the report name (Top most node in the report Inspector)
2. Set the Scriplet class to your package name and class, e.g., org.company.scriptlets.MyChartClass
3. Declare your report variable in iReport.  In this case "PRINTVALUE" would be the variable name.
4. Create a java class that overrides a scriplet method, like beforeDetailEval, e.g.,:

   ```
   @Override
   public void beforeDetailEval() throws JRScriptletException {
           super.beforeDetailEval();
           ...
           this.setVariableValue("PRINTVALUE", true);
   }
   ```

   Since you want to display the category label conditionally for each tick mark, you'll probably need to use a Map of key/val pairs.  key would be category label, value would be true/false for "PRINTVALUE".  Note I did NOT illustrate this in the sample code above but its entirely possible.  Just declare your report variable as a Map, e.g., `HashMap<String, Boolean> hm`.
5. You'll need to add your new scriplet class to the Classpath in iReport.

Hope this helps or at least gets you started.